# Error in installing pyimfit in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install pyimfit using pip install on Jupyter Notebook (Windows) but it shows error no matter what I do.

Regarding Legacy error I tried getting wheels as well. I tried installing with pip install pyimfit --use-pep517 as well.

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [28 lines of output]
  C:\Users\ishaan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
    warnings.warn(
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit
  copying pyimfit\config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit
  copying pyimfit\descriptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit
  copying pyimfit\fitting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit
  copying pyimfit\imfit_funcs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit
  copying pyimfit\psf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit
  copying pyimfit\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit
  copying pyimfit\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit\tests
  copying pyimfit\tests\old_test_model.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit\tests
  copying pyimfit\tests\test_bootstrap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit\tests
  copying pyimfit\tests\test_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit\tests
  copying pyimfit\tests\test_descriptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit\tests
  copying pyimfit\tests\test_fits_and_fitstatistics.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit\tests
  copying pyimfit\tests\test_fitting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit\tests
  copying pyimfit\tests\test_imfit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit\tests
  copying pyimfit\tests\test_oversampled_psf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit\tests
  copying pyimfit\tests\test_temp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit\tests
  copying pyimfit\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyimfit\tests
  running build_ext
  error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyimfit
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [8 lines of output]
  C:\Users\ishaan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
    warnings.warn(
  usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: setup.py --help-commands
     or: setup.py cmd --help
  
  error: option --all not recognized
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for pyimfit
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Running setup.py install for pyimfit did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [9 lines of output]
  C:\Users\ishaan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
    warnings.warn(
  running install
  C:\Users\ishaan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
    warnings.warn(
  running build
  running build_py
  running build_ext
  error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Encountered error while trying to install package.

pyimfit

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tried putting the tar.gz file in the anaconda packages as well.

Comment: [Here the documentation](https://github.com/perwin/pyimfit) covers that they only have ways to install it on MacOS or Linux available. [A recent issue posting reiterates](https://github.com/perwin/pyimfit/issues/5#issuecomment-1529060245) this and offers some possible avenues to purse to **maybe** get around it.